# Unable to use MatTable and DataSource in html file : Angularjs7 Angular material 7

Tags: angular, angular-material-7

I am using the example from [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)
Working Demo : (https://stackblitz.com/angular/bbdqarbrnqk?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts)

1. Using the same material-modules.ts as mentioned in the example.

```
    import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
    import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
    import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
    import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
    import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
    import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
    import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
    import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
    import {
      MatAutocompleteModule,
      MatBadgeModule,
      MatBottomSheetModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatButtonToggleModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatCheckboxModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatDialogModule,
      MatDividerModule,
      MatExpansionModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatMenuModule,
      MatNativeDateModule,
      MatPaginatorModule,
      MatProgressBarModule,
      MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatRippleModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatSliderModule,
      MatSlideToggleModule,
      MatSnackBarModule,
      MatSortModule,
      MatStepperModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatTabsModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatTooltipModule,
      MatTreeModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
    } from '@angular/material';
    
    @NgModule({
      exports: [
        A11yModule,
        CdkStepperModule,
        CdkTableModule,
        CdkTreeModule,
        DragDropModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatBottomSheetModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatTreeModule,
        PortalModule,
        ScrollingModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatRippleModule
      ]
    })
    export class AppMaterialModule {}
```

2. app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from  './app-routing.module';
/* Import material Angular */
import { AppMaterialModule } from './material-module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

/* Call Custom Modules */
import { InstitutionsModule } from './institutions/institutions.module';
import {SchoolsModule} from './schools/schools.module';
import { DepartmentsModule } from './departments/departments.module';
import { ProgramsModule } from './programs/programs.module';

import { BookComponent } from './book/book.component';
import { BookDetailComponent } from './book-detail/book-detail.component';
import { BookCreateComponent } from './book-create/book-create.component';
import { BookEditComponent } from './book-edit/book-edit.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { PagesComponent } from './pages/pages.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BookComponent,
    BookDetailComponent,
    BookCreateComponent,
    BookEditComponent,
    PagesComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    InstitutionsModule,
    SchoolsModule,
    DepartmentsModule,
    ProgramsModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. list.Component.ts: same as example: Added following imports:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

export interface UserData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  progress: string;
  color: string;
}

/** Constants used to fill up our data base. */
const COLORS: string[] = ['maroon', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'olive', 'green', 'purple',
  'fuchsia', 'lime', 'teal', 'aqua', 'blue', 'navy', 'black', 'gray'];
const NAMES: string[] = ['Maia', 'Asher', 'Olivia', 'Atticus', 'Amelia', 'Jack',
  'Charlotte', 'Theodore', 'Isla', 'Oliver', 'Isabella', 'Jasper',
  'Cora', 'Levi', 'Violet', 'Arthur', 'Mia', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth'];

/**
 * @title Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering.
 */

/** Builds and returns a new User. */
function createNewUser(id: number): UserData {
  const name =
      NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))] + ' ' +
      NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))].charAt(0) + '.';

  return {
    id: id.toString(),
    name: name,
    progress: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    color: COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (COLORS.length - 1))]
  };
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-school-list',
  templateUrl: './school-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./school-list.component.css']
})


export class SchoolListComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'progress', 'color'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor() {
    // Create 100 users
    const users = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, k) => createNewUser(k + 1));

    // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

}
```

4. school-list.component.html file

```
<!--mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field-->

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Progress Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="progress">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Progress </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.progress}}% </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Color Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="color">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Color </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

5. schools.modules.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SchoolListComponent } from './school-list/school-list.component';
import { SchoolCreateComponent } from './school-create/school-create.component';
import { SchoolUpdateComponent } from './school-update/school-update.component';
import { SchoolViewComponent } from './school-view/school-view.component';
import { SchoolsRoutingModule } from  './schools-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SchoolListComponent, SchoolCreateComponent, SchoolUpdateComponent, SchoolViewComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SchoolsRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class SchoolsModule { }
```

6. Getting 2 errors: for  and dataSource attribute.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-form-field' is not a known
> element:
>
> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'dataSource'
> since it isn't a known property of 'table'. ("

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: share your code,

Comment: You likely didn't include `DemoMaterialModule` in your `main.ts` imports.

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar code added, have a look please

Comment: @Brian .. I added it in the main i.e. app.module.ts file.. I have added the code here. Have a look please..

Comment: The problem are your modules import and export

Comment: @CryingFreeman What exactly the issue is with import and export modules?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100238/mat-form-field-is-not-a-known-element-angular-5-material2

Comment: @CryingFreeman already added these modules in material-modules.ts

Comment: can you post SchoolsModule code...I believe you need to import your matModules here if you are declaring the SchoolListComponent in it.

Comment: Added the code above @LostJon

Comment: add the `AppMaterialModule` as an import here and give it a whirl.

Comment: @LostJon It works :) Why do I need to add here if I already added in the main app.module.ts file?

Comment: Ill add answer so other folks may benefit

Answer (score 1):

When a component is declared in a module outside of AppModule, you will need to import the Material Module where it is declared.