# Angular Material is failing after upgrading to Angular 14.2.12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

This is a confusing but relatively simple question:

I went from Angular 8 ->>> 14.2.12.  After several builds, deleting package.lock.json (which isn't necessary anymore), Clearing NPM Cache, and deleting node_modules folder then re-running npm install, I'm getting this for every single angular material component...

```
1. If 'mat-tab-group' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab-group' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

53       <mat-tab-group dynamicHeight>
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/shared/info-dialog/personinfo/personinfo.component.ts:12:16
    12   templateUrl: './personinfo.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component PersoninfoComponent.


Error: src/app/shared/Info-dialog/personinfo/personinfo.component.html:54:9 - error NG8001: 'mat-tab' is not a known element:     
1. If 'mat-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

54         <mat-tab label="Home">
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And in app.module.ts I already have this...

CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in app.module.ts

So, why is this continually happening?

Here's the interior section of my package.json

```
"private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.12",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngrx/component": "^14.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.3.3",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.2.6",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "18.2.58",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "^18.2.59",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-popups": "18.2.58",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-base": "18.2.59",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-buttons": "18.2.58",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-inputs": "18.2.59",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-popups": "18.2.58",
    "angular-datatables": "^14.0.2",
    "angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-web-storage": "^14.0.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.10",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "core-js": "^3.29.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.23",
    "datatables.net-autofill": "^2.3.7",
    "datatables.net-autofill-bs4": "^2.5.1",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.13.1",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-bs4": "^1.6.1",
    "datatables.net-datetime": "^1.2.0",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.23",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4": "^4.2.1",
    "datatables.net-keytable": "^2.6.2",
    "datatables.net-keytable-bs4": "^2.8.0",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.4.0",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup-bs4": "^1.3.0",
    "datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4": "^1.3.1",
    "datatables.net-scroller-bs4": "^2.1.0",
    "datatables.net-searchbuilder-bs4": "^1.4.0",
    "datatables.net-searchpanes-bs4": "^2.1.0",
    "datatables.net-staterestore-bs4": "^1.2.0",
    "devextreme": "^21.2.8",
    "devextreme-angular": "^21.2.8",
    "devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery": "^2.8.6",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "2.0.5",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "mat-currency-format": "0.0.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.3.3",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.1.0",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.15",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.7.10",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "parse-address": "^1.1.2",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "streamsaver": "^2.0.4",
    "subsink": "^1.0.2",
    "tar": "^6.1.13",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "url-polyfill": "^1.1.12",
    "web-streams-polyfill": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.12",
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.10.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.23",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jquery.validation": "^1.16.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.13.1",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "ng-lint-report": "^0.2.0",
    "nightwatch": "^2.6.5",
    "nightwatch-api": "^3.0.2",
    "schematics-utilities": "^2.0.2",
    "stylelint": "^14.9.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^5.0.0",
    "stylelint-declaration-use-variable": "^1.7.3",
    "stylelint-order": "^5.0.0",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^2.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }
```

This is Angular Material inside my app.module.ts

```
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/modules/material';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
```

Comment: And the import from `import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';` is inside your App Component, too? Which Version from Angular "Material" do have have installed? You need to update this, too

Comment: See package.json above Flo... thanks

Comment: You can try to run: `ng add @angular/material` again.

Comment: Didn't work.... this is absolutely frustrating

Comment: I don't know about your code.... But do you have imported all important things inside your App Module? Try: Create a brand new app, add Material, create the Commands you need and then look: Whats the different between the both App.Component.ts

Comment: Good thought and yes, the app.module.ts is sound with all proper angular Material items but I will check again, thank you... keep you posted

Comment: If you want you can share your project with me and I can look with you

Comment: I can't it belongs to the federal gov't. BUT, I found that I needed to "export" said Material modules which I found here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100238/mat-form-field-is-not-a-known-element-angular-5-material2